# How do I create this layout in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

I'm trying to make a layout that looks like this in java swing:

[image]

but none of the layout managers provided by swing fit this use case. In android I can simply use a linear layout and set the height of child elements to `wrap-content`, but swing doesn't have any corresponding feature. Swing layout managers tend to set the size of child elements themselves based on the constraints and this is causing issues with textfield.

How do I implement this layout in java swing?

Comment: Not sure what you issue is. You could use a BoxLayout or a GridBagLayout. Or you could nest panels with different layout managers. Maybe start with a BorderLayout. Add a JPanel to the BorderLayout.PAGE_END with the text field and pinned items. Then have another JPanel in the center for the dynamic items to that you can scroll if necessary. We don't have enough information to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: I'm seeing at least two `JList`s at least

Comment: How should it look if the user gives the GUI more width and height? Which elements or white space gets the extra?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It will be a small popup, around 100px wide and as tall as needed, so it will always have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to approach it.

[image]

Comment: Note: This layout never NEEDS to change size when new items are added to the list. The only thing that changes is the size of the scroll bars in the scroll pane that displays it, and those are automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party library

- Swan Layout https://github.com/idayrus/swan-layout

If you use gradle, add this to build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.idayrus:swan-layout:1.01.000'
```

for other build tools, see https://jitpack.io/#idayrus/swan-layout/1.01.000

Example in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val lc = LinearConstraints()
val panel = JPanel(LinearLayout(LinearLayout.VERTICAL))

lc.margin = 10
lc.width = LinearConstraints.MATCH_PARENT
lc.height = LinearConstraints.WRAP_CONTENT
panel.add(JButton("Hello World"), lc)
```